# How long will D3.js v3 be supported?

Tags: d3.js

I couldn't find this info anywhere. I know that D3.js v4 has a lot of v3 bugs fixed and [the new modular approach](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md) is great, but I've got an existing application that has 4 (relatively complex) charts and I can't estimate how many working hours it would take to migrate from v3 to v4. Furthermore, now I'm working on a new map chart and it seems that v3 has already a good map support (then using D3.js v4 wouldn't be mandatory).

When asked about updating v3 examples to v4, [Mike Bostock wrote](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11995332):

> Yep, I’m going to update my examples in-place. Consider it my
>   heavy-handed encouragement to upgrade to 4.0. (For one thing, there
>   are lot of 3.x bugs fixed in 4.0, and I have limited resources to
>   provide free support to old versions.)

However, [the last v3 release (v3.5.17) on GitHub](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases) is recent, 4 May 2016. Therefore I still don't know exactly how long the v3 support will last.

Does anyone have this answer? Or, Mike, do you even have any idea of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3.js v3 is no more supported. Mike [answered me on Twitter](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/764274097995907072):

> I am not fixing bugs or developing new features in v3; my development efforts are solely focused on v4+.

Answer (score 2):

From Mike Bostock on Twitter:

> I am not fixing bugs or developing new features in v3; my development
>   efforts are solely focused on v4+.